# New server action creation with condition

Tags: odoo

I have defined server action to trigger email only if state='tied'. 
However right now system send email soon after creating record with state = 'new'.  Please throw some light on this issue

Basically I need to trigger email ,only if state is equal to tied.

```
  'state': fields.selection([
                ('new','New'),
                ('starts','Starts'),
                ('progress','Progress'),
                ('won','Won'),
                ('lost','Lost'), ('tied','Tied')], 'Stage',readonly=True),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the condition should be: `obj.state == 'tied'`

Comment: I tried with the above  mentioned  conditions But NO luck .    Also below mentioned condition didn't get me the corret result                                                 object.state == 'tied'

Comment: sorry, i dont have another idea :/